# What parameter need to be changed in google analytics reporting chart to display Geo location chart?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I want to integrate chart which is found in google analytics under Reporting Section in my application.

For Eg:like this as shown in below image:
[image]

I have found this website :https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/

But in the above link i cant get the same chart like as shown in above image.

So is there anything to change in the code given in the link reference which could help generate that same chart shown in image or is there any api which can help me generate this same chart??

if i want to display another chart like in :**Geo**==>**Location** then what parameter need to change in below code for that chart:

```
 var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions',
      dimensions: 'ga:date',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday'
    },
    chart: {
      container: 'chart-container',
      type: 'LINE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
```

});

Comment: The embedded api uses the same Dimensions and metrics as the Reporting api basically because it is the reporting api.  See if you can find the dimensions you need here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Comment: but how can i get the same chart like as i shown in image and what coding i do need to change for that?

Comment: the parts where it say metrics and dimensions will need to be changed to reflect the chart that you want to make.   I suggest you read the tutorial. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/ and not just copy the code.

Comment: But still that would render the same chart like as found in google analytics reporting section and as shown in my image??

Comment: I seriously doubt you will get the embedded api to look "exactly" like the website.   I may have to try someday it would make an interring tutorial.  to make something that looks exactly like the website you would probably have to use the reporting API and mash it together with Google charts yourself.  or better yet code your own charts, I am not sure the website exactly uses Google charts.